# Colored output python

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors

So I found some code that formatted a 2048 Game Board so that it didn't look messy when there was more than 1 digit to a number:

```
nlist = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 128, 2, 2, 16, 16]
widths = [max(len(str(nlist[row * 4 + col])) for row in range(4)) + 2 for col in range(4)]
width = sum(widths) + 5
count = 0
for i in range(16):
    print('|{:^{width}}'.format(nlist[i], width=widths[i % 4]), end = '')
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        print("|\n" + '-' * width)
        count = 0
print("")
```

Run this code to make things more clear and change values of nlist to see how the formatting works. So anyways, after I finished the game, I wanted to add colors to make the game easier to understand in terminal so I edited my code to look like this:

```
clist = nlist.copy()
for x in range(16):
    if clist[x] == 2:
        clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;106m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
    if clist[x] == 4:
        clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;105m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
    if clist[x] == 8:
        clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;104m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
    if clist[x] == 16:
        clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;106m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
    if clist[x] == 32:
        clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;106m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
    if clist[x] == 64:
        clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;106m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
    if clist[x] == 128:
        clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;106m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
    if clist[x] == 256:
        clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;106m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
    if clist[x] == 512:
        clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;106m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
    if clist[x] == 1024:
    clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;106m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
    if clist[x] == 2048:
        clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;106m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
    if clist[x] == 4096:
        clist[x] = ' \033[1;37;106m' + str(clist[x]) + '\033[0m '
widths = [max(len(str(nlist[row * 4 + col])) for row in range(4)) + 2 for 
col in range(4)]
width = sum(widths) + 5
count = 0
for i in range(16):
    print('|{:^{width}}'.format(clist[i], width=widths[i % 4]), end = '')
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        print("|\n" + '-' * width)
        count = 0
```

But now the formatting got all messed up and my board looked ugly once again. Is there a possible way to change this code so that it looks like the first code except with colors(right now almost all the colors are the same for times sake. I will change it later). Also, is there any easier way to put colors in a conditional statement?

EDIT:

This is the link to the file with no colors that formats correctly: [2048 that works(no colors)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkx462oy9bkra1p/sys%20copy.py?dl=0)

This is the link to the file with colors that does not format correctly: [2048 that does not work(colors)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cly4gpfn20m16fj/sys.py?dl=0)

Screen shot of me running code: [Screen shot of messed up format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tndebz05jdiobib/Screenshot%202018-07-20%2017.31.55.png?dl=0)

Comment: Adding (proper) ANSI escape sequences should not be changing the number of visible characters. Therefore, your count must be off. This is the first time I've asked this on Stack Overflow: can you add a screenshot of your colored text?

Comment: I will put a link into my whole code in the description

Comment: @J.Doe, Updated, hope it help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two reasons why your colour coding get messed up.

1) You did not define the colour coding for 0, therefore there is always a big formatting gap for zero with other numbers in your code.

2) Your width function did not change with colour function but actually the string length for colored output is much more larger than without one. Therefore I suggest you use a constant number, like 22 or something bigger in your code.
Alternately, you can change

```
widths = [max(len(str(nlist[row * 4 + col])) for row in range(4)) + 2 for col in range(4)]
```

to

```
widths = [max(len(str(nlist[row * 4 + col]))+21 for row in range(4)) + 2 for col in range(4)]
```

To simplify the if structure, I suggest you use a dictionary to lookup for the desired color:

[example](https://github.com/yangshun/2048-python):

```
WHITE_COLOR = "#ffffff"
BACKGROUND_COLOR_GAME = "#92877d"
BACKGROUND_COLOR_CELL_EMPTY = "#9e948a"
BACKGROUND_COLOR_DICT = {   2:"#eee4da", 4:"#ede0c8", 8:"#f2b179", 16:"#f59563", \
                            32:"#f67c5f", 64:"#f65e3b", 128:"#edcf72", 256:"#edcc61", \
                            512:"#edc850", 1024:"#edc53f", 2048:"#edc22e" }
CELL_COLOR_DICT = { 2:"#776e65", 4:"#776e65", 8:"#f9f6f2", 16:"#f9f6f2", \
                    32:"#f9f6f2", 64:"#f9f6f2", 128:"#f9f6f2", 256:"#f9f6f2", \
                    512:"#f9f6f2", 1024:"#f9f6f2", 2048:"#f9f6f2" }
FONT = ("Verdana", 40, "bold")
SCORE_FONT=("Verdana", 20, "bold")
```

For your code, you can make it like

```
nlist = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 128, 2, 2, 16, 16]
color_dict = {0:' \033[1;37;106m0\033[0m ',
              2:' \033[1;37;106m2\033[0m ',4:' \033[1;37;104m4\033[0m ',
              8:' \033[1;37;106m8\033[0m ',16:' \033[1;37;106m16\033[0m ',
              32:' \033[1;37;106m32\033[0m ',64:' \033[1;37;106m64\033[0m ',
              128:' \033[1;37;106m128\033[0m ',256:' \033[1;37;106m256\033[0m ',
              512:' \033[1;37;106m512\033[0m ',1024:' \033[1;37;106m1024\033[0m ',
              2048:' \033[1;37;106m2048\033[0m ',4096:' \033[1;37;106m4096\033[0m '}
count = 0
for i in range(16):
    print('|{:^{width}}'.format(color_dict[nlist[i]], width=22), end = '')   #This line is modified.
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        print("|\n" + '-')
        count = 0
```

Comment: How can I incorporate this into my code(I have never used dictionaries before?

Comment: @ J.Doe, I have no idea how you can achieve color coding in python without import any module. In the link provided above, tkinter module is deployed, and the color is referenced from the dictionary provided above. Example: if score=2.  Color=BACKGROUND_COLOR_DICT[score].  Color is "#eee4da", which is grey. http://www.color-hex.com/color/eee4da

Comment: I never said I can't import anything but how does this work in my conditional statement without the formatting getting messed up

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus He wants colour formatting in the terminal output, not in a GUI application. He already showed in the question how that can be done (with ANSI escape sequences). When I understand the question right, the user wants to know how he can use it without messing up the printed grid formatting.

Comment: @J. Doe, I suspect the color of your table is messed up because they all use one color '\e[0;106m'.

Comment: @michaPau,sorry sir. I think the reason is that widths here is not long enough for escape sequences to have same distance between two elements. I have test some value and found width 22 is good enough.....

Comment: If I do that list index is out of range.

Comment: Edited, sorry, the 21 should be outside the len(str(nlist[row * 4 + col])).

Comment: Btw do i keep that `width = sum(width)+5` piece of code or do I remove it

Comment: `can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176477/discussion-between-marcus-aurelianus-and-j-doe).

Comment: Im getting that for `widths = [max(len(str(nlist[row * 4 + col])+21) for row in range(4)) + 2 for col in range(4)]`

Comment: my bad, make it. widths = [max(len(str(nlist[row * 4 + col]))+21 for row in range(4)) + 2 for col in range(4)]

Answer (score 0):

Use `colored` from `termcolor` modules for colors

```
from termcolor import colored
nlist = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 128, 2, 2, 16, 16]
color = {n:'cyan' for n in nlist}
color[4] = 'red'

widths = [max(len(str(nlist[row * 4 + col])) for row in range(4)) + 16 for col in range(4)]
width = sum(widths) + 5
count = 0
for i in range(16):
    print('|{:^{width}}'.format(colored(nlist[i], 'white', 'on_'+color[nlist[i]]), width=widths[i % 4]), end = '')
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        print("|\n" + '-' * width)
        count = 0
print("")
```

**Output**
I do see the following output in colors

```
|  2  |  4   |  8   |  16  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 32  |  64  | 128  | 256  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 512 | 1024 | 2048 | 4096 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 128 |  2   |  2   |  16  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```